# each loop in rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

house model

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :categories, :through => :category_join_table

def features_to_html_class  
  "#{price} #{rooms} #{guests} #{{categories.name do |cat| cat.name}}"
end
end
```

House index template

```
- @houses.each do |house|
  .item{:class => house.features_to_html_class }
```

The values price, rooms, guests are parsed correctly in the view (filtering purposes), but not the categories. What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
categories.map{|cat|cat.name|}.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to have multiple classes for the same category name if there is a space.

```
Top Articles
Articles
```

Would produce:

```
class="Top Articles Articles"
```

You could go a step further and replace spaces with dashes, and downcase it all:

```
"#{ categories.map{ |cat| cat.name.parameterize }"

class="top-articles articles"
```

EDIT:

As Anthony pointed out in the comments, if you're using Rails, you can use [parameterize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/parameterize).

Comment: or use `String#parameterize` to convert a string to a standardized representation

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through each name categori so you need to use:

```
{categories.name.each { |cat| cat.name}}
```

Comment: categories.name will surely raise a NoMethod error. And the `each` method will return the original array object. You should use map instead. Try it yourself on an irb console.